# Using Array.Copy in 2d Array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have a 2 dimensional array.
Like,
  (0,1)
  (0,2)
  (0,3)
  (1,1)
  (1,2)
  (1,3)
  (2,1)
  (2,2)
  (2,3)

How can i use `Array.Copy` to copy only the 2nd index in a new array.
Like only,
  (2,1)
  (2,2)
  (2,3)

Or is there any other way.

Comment: You could use a foreach construction.. but that is probably not realy effcient.

Comment: @BartTeunissen not really efficient? There are not too many things more efficient than looping through simple arrays. There you have a link (in C# but instructive anyway): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483893/is-array-copy-faster-than-for-loop-for-2d-arrays

Comment: I understand that thats the case, but a foreach loop is more than one line of code, and i wasn't sure if there was an easier sollution.. that is what is was trying to say.

Comment: @varocarbas...please suggest an answer...not able to conclude with the link

Comment: @BartTeunissen All clear. But some times, lines of code and efficiency are mixed up: a lower number of lines does not mean higher efficiency. A single line can call a really complex set of functions. For example, the "simple" arrays require more lines of code than "more complex" collection (e.g., List); but they are much more efficient as far as the complex collections need more resources to perform each single action.

Comment: I haven't written any answer because I only use Array.Copy with 1D arrays (otherwise, loops). I am not even sure about its exact applicability to 2D arrays (have read people talking about that, but never seen a working implementation). There are alternative approaches, but also never use them. Sorry but I am not in a position to answer this question (just to clarify the comment above).

Comment: And i haven't posted an anwser because i'm only into c# and not VB.net :) I have found a link though which you could use. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834233/how-to-foreach-through-a-2-dimensional-array

Comment: I don't really understand which elements you want in your new array, it's difficult to understand from your example. Do you want a new array containing all the values from the second dimension of the array?

Answer (score 0):

Array.copy( source_array, 6, destin_array,  )